# AJAX Form Validation to see if course already exist always return true

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to validate my course name field if the course name inputted already exist using AJAX, but my ajax function always return the alert('Already exist') even if i inputted data that not yet in the database. Please help. Here is my code. Thanks.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 3000;


$('#course_name').keyup(function(){
typingTimer = setTimeout(check_course_name_exist, doneTypingInterval);
});


$('#course_name').keydown(function(){
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});



function check_course_name_exist()
   {

   var course_name=$("#course_name").val();

    var postData= {
    'course_name':course_name
   };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/courses/check_course_name_existence",
        data: postData,
        success: function(msg)
        {


        if(msg == 0)
        {
         alert('Already Exist!');
         return false;
        }

        else
         {
         alert('Available');
         return false;
         }


         return false;
        }
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
  return false;
   }



  </script>
```

Controller:

```
function check_course_name_existence()
{
 $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');

 $result = $this->course_booking_model->check_course_name_exist($course_name);
 if ($result)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Model:

```
function check_course_name_exist($course_name)
{

    $this->db->where("course_name",$course_name);
    $query=$this->db->get("courses");

   if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [console.log()](https://getfirebug.com/logging) function from firebug. This way you will know exactly what the ajax returns. Example:

```
success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

This way you also know the type of the result variable.

Comment: I've tried  console.log(msg) but it doesn't return something. Where I would be able to see its output?

Comment: You have to load the website in [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/) extension installed. After the page has loaded, press **F12**. It will open **Firebug** window. After that, click the console tab, **activate it** and **reload** the webpage. There you will see the result of **any** ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery, and Javascript generally, does not have access to the Boolean values that the PHP functions are returning. So either they return `TRUE` or `FALSE` does not make any difference for the JS part of your code.
You should try to `echo` something in your controller and then make your Javascript comparison based on that value.